# what does it mean by email address as label generating pubic/private rsa key pair?

Tags: ssh

In https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-linux

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
# Creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label Generating public/private rsa key pair.
```

Is `your_email@example.com` an argument to the the option `-C`?

What does "label" mean?
can it be any string, not necessarily my email account registered with github?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, `your_email@example.com` is [the argument for `-C`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1), which allows you to specify the comment attached to the generated key. The comment is simply text appended to the key in your public key file, and is typically used as a label for your key (*e.g.* on [GitHub](https://github.com/settings/keys) which is what you seem interested in).

The default comment is your username @ the hostname of the system you generate your key on, but it can be any string you wish.

Answer (score 8):

> What does "label" mean? can it be any string, not necessarily my email account registered with github?

Yes. It can be any string. As pointed out, it is a [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/743548/what-significance-does-the-user-host-at-the-end-of-an-ssh-public-key-file-hold/743566#743566) that is available only in the public key and does not have any significant meaning in scope of OpenSSH. It is just for you to distinguish the keys on your disk, on the remote hosts (`authorized_keys`) and when you list them from the `ssh-agent`.

Moreover, some other SSH implementation might add different meaning to that part (use it as a username as some embedded devices do).

Using `username@hostname` is a good convention, because this pair basically distinguishes any host (if you don't use `localhost` everywhere.

Comment: It also can be beneficial to add .local to the hostname if it's not a public domain. In fact, this is the default behavior of OSX. I.E. steve@mycomputer.local